# pandas DataFrame - comparing two columns based on condition being true

Tags: python, pandas, iteration, dataframe

I have the following pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Open': [1.20443, 1.20438, 1.20464, 1.20443, 1.20443, 1.2049, 1.20444, 1.20443],
               'High': [1.20447, 1.20467, 1.20497, 1.20446, 1.20447, 1.20505, 1.20446, 1.20446],
               'Low':  [1.20429, 1.20436, 1.20464, 1.20439, 1.20429, 1.20350, 1.20441, 1.20439],
               'Close': [1.20438, 1.20466, 1.20486, 1.20439, 1.20438, 1.20497, 1.20446, 1.20439],
               'Support': [1.20346, 1.20346, 1.20361, 1.20363, 1.20362, 1.20364, 1.20367, 1.20360],
               'BR': [False, False, True, False, False, True, False, False]})
```

What I want to do is iterate through column `BR` until `True`, then compare that row value of `Low` to the previous row value of `Support` and iterate through from that point unit `Low` is less than `Support`, return `True` or `False` if does not happen, then continue iterating `BR` from the point left off.

i.e. row 2 `BR = True` compare `low` row 2 to `Support` row 1 until `low < Support` in row 5, continue iterating `BR` from row 3.

I can do it with for loops and if statements, but this is a large dataset and that will take a long time so I am hoping there is an optimized way that pandas can handle this.  I have tried map and apply but can not seem to get past the need to iterate over each row item by item.

Comment: Could you create a dummy column that is a duplicate of `Support` but shifted down one to put the previous `Support` value on the same row as the current `Low`?  Ex: `df['Support1'] = df['Support'].shift()` and iterate row by row to see if `Low` is less than `Support1`.

Comment: I could, but that would not eliminate the problem of then iterating to see if true. I am actually trying to compare two different conditions as I iterate, 1.  if 'Low' < 'Support' and 2. if 'High' > a stop loss value passed to the function (or set previously).  The condition hit first would then determine 1. True or 2. False

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `np.where`.

```
df['Answer'] = np.where((df['BR'] == True) & (df['Low'] < df['Support']), True,
                        np.where((df['BR'] == True) & (df['High'] > 1.20504), True,
                                 False))
```

Or you might be able to combine it into one `np.where`:

```
df['Answer'] = np.where(((df['BR'] == True) & (df['Low'] < df['Support'])) | (df['BR'] == True) & (df['High'] > 1.20504), True,
                        False)
```

Comment: This has potential, I have been looking at it yesterday and today and may get this concept to work.  If I come up with anything will post.